# JSOn parsing data shows different values for same object in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When i NSLog affecteddate values it shows correct but when i store it in var it gives wrong value

```
   SBJsonParser *parser= [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=bareListEventsByCategory&appid=620&category-selected=%@&counties-selected=Vest-Agder,Aust-Agder&range=0-10", test];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];




NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
NSArray *results = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
appDelegate.books1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
appDelegate.dates =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
appDelegate.books2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
appDelegate.books3=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
appDelegate.books4=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
appDelegate.books5=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
appDelegate.books6=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
appDelegate.books7=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
appDelegate.books8=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
appDelegate.books9=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
appDelegate.books10=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSArray *activitiesArray;

mycount=[results count];
for (int j=0;j<[results count]; j++) {

    NSDictionary *dictOne = [results objectAtIndex:j];
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictOne objectForKey:@"date"]);
    Date  *aDate = [[Date alloc] initWithDictionary:[results objectAtIndex:j]];
    [appDelegate.dates addObject:aDate];
    [aDate release];
    activitiesArray = [dictOne objectForKey:@"events"];




     for (int i=0; i<[activitiesArray count]; i++) {

        int testcount =[activitiesArray count];
        NSDictionary *dictTwo = [activitiesArray objectAtIndex:i];

        NSDictionary *eventDict=[dictTwo objectForKey:@"event"];



        //  NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictOne objectForKey:@"date"]);
        //  NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictTwo objectForKey:@"affectedDate"]);
        //  NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [eventDict objectForKey:@"location"]);



        NSInteger*date=[dictTwo objectForKey:@"affectedDate"];

        NSInteger*affecteddate=[dictTwo objectForKey:@"affectedDate"];

        NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictTwo objectForKey:@"affectedDate"]);

        NSString*appId =[eventDict objectForKey:@"appId"];
        NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [eventDict objectForKey:@"eventId"]);

        NSInteger*eventId=[eventDict objectForKey:@"eventId"];

        int next=[affecteddate intValue];
        int next_int = [eventId intValue];



        NSString*location=[eventDict objectForKey:@"location"];
        NSString*municipality=[eventDict objectForKey:@"municipality"];
        NSString*title=[eventDict objectForKey:@"title"];




    Book1 *aBook=[[Book1 alloc] initWithDate:date affecteddate:affecteddate   eventId:eventId location:location municipality:municipality title:title];
```

Book1 class
               @interface Book1 : NSObject {
           NSInteger*date;
            NSInteger*affecteddate;

```
        NSString *title;
        NSString *location;
       NSString *municipality;


      NSInteger eventId;

      NSString* event;

           }

              @property(nonatomic,readwrite)    NSInteger eventId;
              @property(nonatomic,retain)   NSString* event;
              @property(nonatomic) NSInteger *date;

              @property(nonatomic,readwrite)NSInteger* affecteddate;
              @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *title;

              @property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *location;
              @property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *municipality;

                -(id)initWithDate:(NSInteger *)d affecteddate:(NSInteger *)ad eventId:(NSInteger*)eId location:(NSString *)l municipality:(NSString *)m title:(NSString *)t ;



             @end
```

Comment: What is "correct" here and what is "wrong?"

Comment: What does NSLog output that you believe is "correct" and what does the ivar contain that you believe is "wrong?" You shouldn't need a page of code to demonstrate this.

Comment: i am getting this data from JSON data i have checked in data NSLog out put is correct i am also posting JSON parsing code also

Answer (score 0):

First you have:

```
NSInteger*affecteddate=[dictTwo objectForKey:@"affectedDate"];
```

later

```
int next=[affecteddate intValue];
```

`intValue` is not valid on an integer

You probably want:

```
NSNumber *date = [dictTwo objectForKey:@"affectedDate"];

NSNumber *affecteddate = [dictTwo objectForKey:@"affectedDate"];
```

may declare like this in book object to assign this values

```
   NSNumber *affecteddate;
  @propert(nonatomic,retain)
```

Comment: this gives worng value not appropriate same i am using for eventId as shown above its working fine

Comment: i have posted Book class code so how may i declare affecteddate there

Comment: [dictTwo objectForKey:@"affectedDate"] returns an object, probably an NSInteger *, not an int.  Only objects can be put in a dictionary, array or other object container type.

Comment: so how may declare this and access them from Book object

Comment: NSInteger is _not_ an object, it is an int.  NSNumber is an object that can hold a number.

Comment: how may assing this NSNumber value to NSString b/c i have to pass this value to url

Comment: i am converting this NSNumber into NSString but it gives exception

Comment: You can get a string value with stringValue, NSNumber *numberObject = [dictTwo objectForKey:@"affectedDate"]; NSString *stringValue = [numberObject stringValue];  That may not be the format you want, in that case use NSString stringWithFormat.